# Why is it okay to transmit authentication/session cookies over plaintext?

Tags: security, http, cookies

We all know that it's bad to transmit usernames and passwords over plaintext, since they can be easily viewed by anybody looking at the packets, so we use HTTPS to encrypt this data.

I've noticed that many websites just use HTTPS for the login form and use regular HTTP for all other pages (such as StackOverflow). Couldn't somebody see the cookie (like a session cookie) returned from a login form and inject that into their own web requests? Although it won't expose the username and password, it seems like they could impersonate another user by doing this.

Let's say I'm snooping into my friend's internet connection. After my friend authenticates in HTTPS, the server and my friend begin communicating over HTTP and transmit the cookies in plaintext. What is preventing me from using this cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really. If an attacker steals the cookie and then uses it, this is known as [Session Hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

[StackOverflow are aware of this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69171/241749) and have been looking at moving towards HTTPS everywhere (site network wide).

To prevent a cookie from ever being sent over an insecure connection, the [Secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) should be set. This will stop the browser from sending it over HTTP connections, even if an attacker tried to make it leak from their own site (very easy to do, an attacker could just include `<img src="http://www.example.com/anything.jpg" />` in their own site to cause an unsecure cookie to be sent over HTTP and conduct a [MITM attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack)).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is preventing you from using the cookie and stealing his sessions. It's a very poor security practice to send cookies over HTTP. In fact this very weakness was used by the [Firesheep Firefox extension](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) that made headlines a few years ago. Since then some sites (notably Facebook and Gmail) have moved to HTTPS only. Other sites should follow suit.